# Mongoose findById returns the empty doc

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to implement CRUD operations using MEAN stack. I'm facing a problem on getting user by Id. It's showing the status true but it returns an empty document.

This is my model:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Full name can\'t be empty '
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: 'user name can\'t be empty ',
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: 'email can\'t be empty ',
        unique: true
    });

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

in my controller:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
const User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports.getuser = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id : ${req.params.id}`);

    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
        if(!err){ res.status(200).json({status: true, user}); }
        else{ console.log('Error in retriving User :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });    
}
```

This is the route:

```
router.get('/:id', jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken, ctrlUser.getuser);
```

while checking in the postman I'm getting status: true but it returns a blank document.
I'm not getting what's going on anyone please help. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: May be a problem with the `_id` type? On the database it's (I think) an `ObjectId` but you provides a `String` to the `findById` function?

Comment: but it worked previously. is there any other way. I want to get user by id.

Comment: I would try with `User.findById(ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id))`, in order to remove any doubt about type conversion problems...

Comment: I tried it's not working.

Comment: Can you try adding `console.log(err, user)` before the `if` statement?

Comment: it displays nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188796/discussion-between-sun-and-pietro-martinelli).

Answer (score -1):

There could be several reasons why you're not able to find and return a user. I'd go through this checklist to see what might be occurring:

1. When you define your schema the `required` field takes a boolean or a function, not a string. To be safe it would make sense to change your strings to `true` in order to make sure all new db records contain these fields. (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options)
2. When you import the model in your controller there is no need to call `mongoose.model` again; this step is performed in your model file. Make sure you're exporting the `mongoose.model('User', userSchema)` object in the model file/module and then do a normal `const User = require(<pathToModelFile>);` in the controller module.

*If this still doesn't work...*

3. You'll want to make sure your record is in fact saved in your db. Run a mongo shell in terminal by running `$ mongo` and use commands found here to use your db and search the User collection: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/

This is how I would normally code my model and controllers (with routes):

Model file - Note you do need to require Mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Controller/Router -

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('User');

router.get('/:id', jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken, async (req, res) => {
   try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json({status: true, user});
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({err: e});
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: As you suggested I set all required fields to true and exported my mongoose.model as you suggest in the second step and also I have few records in my database. but still, it's not working.

Comment: @TylerGoodman, when will the required field take a function? What can you do with the function?